# 'src/dsp/yuv.h' file not found react native iOS

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have been trying to run the app but Xcode is yelling at with 'src/dsp/yuv.h' file not found. The issue is coming from libwebp~1.3.2 pod. My minimum deployment target is 11.0. I have ran the following command to update the pods:

```
pod update
```

but still no luck!